# Alterar resolução de imagem via código java

Tags: java, imagem

fala galera to bolando um programa pra automatizar postagem em um blog, e preciso que as imagens fiquem em 500x500 sempre  tem como eu receber o arquivo e redimensionar via código em java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sempre tem um jeito rs, dá uma olhada na biblioteca [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator), faz exatamente o que você precisa e sem escrever muito código.

Exemplo:

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("imagem.jpg"))
    .size(500, 500)
    .toFile(new File("nova_imagem.jpg"));
```